# Trying to push an existing repository from the command line

Tags: github, push, git-remote, github-for-windows

I am trying to push an existing repo on my GitHub Account (remote depository), but nothing happens at all:

[image]

When I check the page at GitHub, there is no change or updates at all.

Comment: It says that there is nothing to commit. Have you run `git add <file>`?

Comment: @vandench yes, I've already run that code before, but got no success.

Comment: Well do you actually have any local changes on that branch? What does `git status` tell you?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes.Actually it does not give any answer. When I open the GitHub online, there is no update or additional files I've created.